# Reserved word as member of enum

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums, reserved-words, reserved

I wanted to make a python Enum work having a reserved word as member.

```
class Test(Enum):

    one = "one"
    is_ = "is"
```

I wanted to customize `__name__` to have the usual syntax return

```
>>> print(Test.is_.name)
is
```

So how do I customize `__name__`, `__getattribute__` or `__getattr__` to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of mucking about with the internals, you could use the [`Functional API`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#functional-api) instead:

```
Test = Enum('Test', [('one', 'one'), ('is', 'is'), ('is_', 'is')])
```

and in use:

```
>>> Test.one
<Test.one: 'one'>

>>> Test.is
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    test.is
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

>>> Test.is_
<Test.is: 'is'>

>>> Test['is']
<Test.is: 'is'>

>>> Test['is_']
<Test.is: 'is'>

>>> Test('is')
<Test.is: 'is'>

>>> list(Test)
[<Test.one: 'one'>, <Test.is: 'is'>]
```

Comment: You are absolutely right @Ethan Furman I only remembered Functional API after having asked the question, because I always favor class syntax (when possible) in creating enum.

Answer (score 2):

It's stored in a *single underscore* variable:

```
>>> Test.is_._name_ = 'is'                                                                                                                                       
>>> Test.is_.name                                                                                                                                                
'is'
```

This will also fix up the repr's, and the call by member value still works:

```
>>> list(Test)                                                                                                                                                   
[<Test.one: 'one'>, <Test.is: 'is'>]
>>> Test('is')                                                                                                                                                   
<Test.is: 'is'>
```

Attribute access will still have to use the declared name, of course, because otherwise it would be a syntax error.

To enable call by member name, patch it into the map:

```
>>> Test.is_._name_ = 'is'                                                                                                                                       
>>> Test._member_map_['is'] = Test.is_                                                                                                                           
>>> Test['is']                                                                                                                                                   
<Test.is: 'is'>
```

If you need more than a simple alias here, then you might want to remove the original name and/or take care to preserve ordering in the member map.

Comment: Note that this breaks accessing members by name, too; try `Test[Test.is_.name]`